# Native Look of Radio buttons in jQuery Mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am  working on an android  App using jQuery mobile,phonegap in which i have  form  i need to make the radio elements to be as native ones not as button like this 
                  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKEGa.png
 , i do that by adding  data-role="none"  , but the radio size " selected circle " is too small how can i enlarge the radio size ?

please help me,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Omar how can i do that ? can you help me please?

Comment: Check this http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-checkbox-radio/

Answer (score 1):

You can basically style the fields as you wish. For example, the below theme has the style as you expect.

http://driftyco.github.io/graphite/

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
  <legend>Choose a pet:</legend>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-1" value="choice-1" checked="checked" />
  <label for="radio-choice-1">Cat</label>

  <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-2" value="choice-2"  />
  <label for="radio-choice-2">Dog</label>

  <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-3" value="choice-3"  />
  <label for="radio-choice-3">Hamster</label>

  <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-4" value="choice-4"  />
  <label for="radio-choice-4">Lizard</label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: i have styled them as native , actually what i need is to enlarge the radio size " the circle that we check it " .

Comment: @user this could be an option. Another option is to make your own styles.