# Change Size of Radio Buttons In JQuery Mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I have the following Radio buttons in jQuery Mobile as in the picture, and I need to increase the radio size since it is too small, I have adjusted the width and height attributes but it did not work.

How can I do that since I don't want them appear as buttons, I need them in this look?

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
<legend>Layout view:</legend>
<input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="List" value="List" checked="checked" data-role="none" />
<label for="List">List</label>

<input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="Grid" value="Grid"  data-role="none" />
<label for="Grid">Grid</label>

<input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="Gallery" value="Gallery"  data-role="none"/>
<label for="Gallery">Gallery</label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Are you asking for more space between the 3 options, or are you asking for a bigger circle image for each of them?

Comment: i need to enlarge the  radio circle (bigger circle image for each radio)

Comment: @ezanker how can i do that?? please help me

Comment: Problem is some browsers allow this and some don't. input[type=radio]{    width: 2em; height: 2em; } will work in IE11 but not Chrome. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920281/how-to-change-the-size-of-the-radio-button-using-css  You can use custom images or maybe if you space the items more the size won't matter?

Comment: I am working on android app using jQuery mobile

Comment: i tried this css statement it didnt work the circle still too small

Comment: possible duplicate of [Native Look of Radio buttons in jQuery Mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224982/native-look-of-radio-buttons-in-jquery-mobile)

Comment: Would this work for you: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/s2R7w/ ?

Comment: @ezanker thanks for your response,can we remove the border around the radios ? and how ?

Comment: @ezanke please  i really need an answer, can we do that via css ?

Comment: Sure: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/s2R7w/1/